# Infinitives with "ought not"

Tags: grammar, infinitives, bare-infinitive, semi-modals

Most of the references I can find about the word “ought” indicate that even when negating it, you should use an infinitive: “You ought not to go there.”

That sounds quite bad to my ear. Much better sounding to me is “You ought not go there.” Without the “to”.

Comparing this to similar usage of “should” does no good, since they can’t even agree *without* negation: “should go” versus “ought to go”.

Now that I think about it, I am suddenly far from certain that “ought to go” actually contains an infinitive in the first place; maybe “ought to” works together as some part of speech that modifies the verb, rather than “to go” being a unit.

I’m obviously no linguist. Can someone shed some light on this for me? Specifically, can you explain the function/part-of-speech of each word in a way that makes it clear whether "to go" or "go" is more correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Peter Shor's answer, however, looking at this phrase in the [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) corpus, there seems to be an exception that is most prevalent in spoken English where *ought not be* is a frequent although still less common alternative to *ought not to be*.  For example:

> ...one could argue then that President Bush ought not be succeeding.

*2005 Tavis Smiley, PBS*

Searching a selection of classic texts I found no instances of *ought not be*, and British English also appears to reject omission of the 'to' in negative ought.  So I would tentatively conclude that this is a development in contemporary American English.

Comment: That is a very interesting app. If I'm reading it correctly, it seems as though in a full 30% of cases of "ought not", it is in my preferred construction — followed by a word other than "to". In 12% of cases it is followed by "be" and in 18% it's followed by some other word.

Comment: Yes this seems to be the case.  Yours appears to be an accepted construction in contemporary US English.  But I found classical and British writers *always* use 'to'.  Have updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Google NGrams agrees; *ought not be* seems to be found without *to* only in American English, and only in the last century or so.

Answer (score 5):

It's usually *ought not to*. The [Google Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=ought+not%2C+ought+not+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) below
shows that most of the time *ought not* is used, it is the first two words of *ought not to*. Many of the remaining cases appear to be constructions like *ought not publicly to,* with an adverb between the *not* and the *to*.

[image]

Comment: +1 You can also do similar comparisons for e.g. "ought not to go" vs "ought not go" and see that the former is hugely more common (though in any case, use of "ought" has declined hugely in the 20th century).

Comment: [Here](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=ought+not+go%2Cought+not+to+go&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) is the link to that comparison.

Comment: @NeilCoffey Does *“Oughtn’t you give him a call?”* sound like it “needs” a *to* particle inserted between *you* and *give* to your ear, or would that sound worse to you? I realize it’s completely subjective, varying by age and register and education and station and region and who knows what else, but to me adding the particle makes it sound weird. At least in negative interrogatives, for me *oughtn’t* works exactly like the way *shouldn’t* works. And no, I don’t think I say it much.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe things have changed in just a few years, but a Google search reveals:

"ought not go" is 30 times as common as "ought not to go";
"ought not do" is 4 times as common as "ought not to do";
"ought not be" is about 25% more common than "ought not to be."