# Is it appropriate to omit "to" after "ought"?

Tags: modal-verbs, infinitives, bare-infinitive, semi-modals

Is it appropriate to omit *to* after *ought*?

> I ought to be disciplined for my insolence.

Vs.

> I ought be disciplined for my insolence.

Is it okay to omit the *to*?

Comment: I'm intrigued that negation affects my sense of how acceptable it is to omit "to". Although it's [less common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ought+not+do+that%2Cought+not+to+do+that&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), I have no problem at all with **You ought not do that**. But, for example, [You ought do that](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ought+do+that%2Cought+to+do+that&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) (which is far less common) sounds decidedly odd to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It does sound better when negative. I find that interesting.

Comment: It sounds better because _ought_ is a semantic modal auxiliary and omission of the _to_ (i.e, treating the infinitive complement as a modal would and omitting _to_) is a negative polarity phenomenon, like the use of _need_ and _dare_ as modals:
 - *I need go ~ I need not go.   (modal)
 -  I need to go ~ I don't need to go.  (non-modal)

Comment: More on [Negative Polarity Items](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) and [Negation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf)

Comment: Related: [Infinitives with “ought not”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36112/infinitives-with-ought-not)

Comment: The _to_ in the periphrastic modal spelled _ought to_ is not a preposition but rather an enclitic on _ought_, which is why it's spelled "oughta" in eye dialect, like _wanna_ and _hafta_. You can't leave the _to_ off those, either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not typical.

The [*American Heritage Dictionary* entry for *ought*](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/ought) has the following usage note:

> Unlike other auxiliary verbs, *ought* usually takes *to* with its accompanying verb: *We ought to go.* Sometimes the accompanying verb is dropped if the meaning is clear: *Should we begin soon? Yes, we ought to.* In questions and negative sentences, especially those with contractions, *to* is also sometimes omitted: *Oughtn't we be going soon?* This omission of *to*, however, is not common in written English.

Answer (score 6):

The omission of *to* is more frequent in American English. Quirk & al. (*A Grammar of Contemporary English*) say:

> *Ought* regularly has the *to*-infinitive, but AmE occasionally has the bare infinitive in negative sentences and in questions (although *should* is commoner in both cases):
>   - *You oughtn't smoke so much.*
>   - *Ought you smoke so much?*

Comment: I must admit my first thought was those examples look archaic, rather than American. But some Americans are happy to omit *"to **be**"* in ["my car needs washed"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24163/), so perhaps that's a related [non-]usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'd say that they're unrelated; the lack of *to* in AmEng *ought* constructions is a completely different absence than the lack of *to be* in the Western Pennsylvania *needs verbed* construction.

Comment: @PeterShor: In retrospect, I suppose that's obvious (even Pennsylvanians don't say *My car needs **be** washed*, regardless of whatever other "syntactic shortcomings" they tolerate! :) But your ping here led me to re-examine [your answer to the earlier question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/36116/2637) about *negating* contexts. The NGram link is dead, so I can't see exactly how you made your chart (implying that we're just as likely to omit ***to*** as include it, in contexts like *You ought not [to] do that*), but...

Comment: [...this is my chart,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ought+not+do%2Cought+not+to+do%2Cought+to+not+do&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) which shows that we nearly always *do* include the infinitive marker there. And I see no significant difference between BrE and AmE corpuses for that chart.

Answer (score 3):

British English requires the *to*-infinitive. (I didn't know until reading the above comments that American English allowed its omission.)

Answer (score 0):

The use of ought w/out the "to' is a lovely locution when the underlying intention is imperative.  "My name ought be included" = "Include my name."  I vote for its acceptance.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).