# What is the meaning of "ought not"?

Tags: meaning, verbs, meaning-in-context, negation, modal-verbs

Consider this example:

> A few strong branches over water reach for what they ought not reach.

Which of the meanings comes closest to “ought not” in this sentence?
Is it “doesn't have to”, “should not” or “must not”?

Comment: Verbs like *ought, should, must, have to* express degrees of desirability or probability, neither of which really apply to non-sentient things like branches. Maybe the branches "ought not reach" according to the writer's preconceived notions of whether they were likely to. Or maybe it's a type of plant that can extract soil-based nutrients from far-reaching branches (like weeping willows, I think). If the soil on the other side of the river contains toxins, figuratively the plant might very much "wish" not to reach across and thus poison itself.

Comment: All modals have intransitive epistemic senses about possibility and probability, and volitional deontic senses about permission and obligation. Deontic senses apply to people, but living things are borderline. All the interpretations FF offers work fine, in context, because [modals](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html) underdetermine, like most semantics.

Comment: @John: Absolutely. I had no conscious knowledge of all this "underdeterminism" before I came to ELU. It's practically a weighty tome in itself, but I still really like [this answer by Cerberus](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21706/why-do-we-say-supposed-to-for-should-have) about the issue.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the negation is inside the scope of _ought (to)_ in _ought not to P_; i.e, the logic is ▢¬P, although the square has rounded corners, as a weak necessity modal. This is the same as _should not_ or _shouldn't_. I don't hear or use _oughtn't_, though I encounter it written occasionally, but it has the same semantics, too.

Comment: > Ought not Jason to have slept after working all day long. Compared to > Jason ought not sleep after working all day. With simple changing of the position of Jason, it changes the meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some might prefer the sentence to have *to* before *reach*, but otherwise it is well-formed. It’s impossible to be sure of the meaning out of context. It could be *should not* or it could be *must not*, or possibly something else, but not *doesn't have to* (which would in any case have to be *don't have to* in order to agree in number with the subject).

Comment: I agree [ought not to do](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ought+not+do%2Cought+not+to+do&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) normally includes **"to"**, but I can't say my "inner grammarian's ear" particularly pricks up if it's missing. On the other hand, I have to admit I'd much rather hear **"to"** included in "non-negating" constructions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I did wonder about it, but felt its omission here sounded a little precious. I have amended my answer to avoid suggesting that its absence is impossible. Certainly, a sentence such as ‘We ought not say anything in case we’re misunderstood’ is permissible.

Comment: Quite so. But *‘We ought say something lest our silence be mistaken for tacit consent’* doesn't really work for me. Anyway, now I can upvote the answer with a clear conscience. It's not a clear-cut sign of illiteracy to drop "to" in negating constructions - I wish I could have found an example from a well-respected author to establish that point, but it's an awkward one to search for.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The OED has 536 citations for ‘ought not to’. There must be some from well-respected authors among them. I’ve only lighted on this from Rossetti: ‘we ought not to lack for adventures’. Doesn’t ‘ought’ always have to be followed by ‘to’ in positive statements?

Comment: No no - I was talking about 'ought not do' as opposed to 'ought not **to** do'. For which the Rossetti equivalent would be ‘we ought not lack for adventures’. [Here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&newwindow=1&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22ought+not+lack%22&pbx=1&oq=%22ought+not+lack%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=8360750l8370640l23l8371500l22l22l0l0l0l5l234l2981l5.16.1l22l0&biw=1238&bih=857&cad=cbv&sei=YlT_TrjlEont8QPN0cTIAQ) are a handful of such, but "not lack" here bothers me a bit more than "not do".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I suspect there’s a difference between ‘ought to’ when it expresses obligation and ‘ought to’ when, as in the Rossetti example, it expresses deduction.

Comment: It's a good theory, but I can't see any significant difference in Google Books for the relative predominance of *"ought not to do"* over *"ought not do"*, when I precede them by *"he"* (presumably mainly "obligation/recommendation" contexts) as opposed to *"it"* (mainly "deduction/expectation" contexts, I'd have thought).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2104/discussion-between-barrie-england-and-fumblefingers)

Answer (score 4):

There appear to be several issues entangled here.

One issue, the answer to the OP's original question, is that they're all different [modal constructions](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html), each with different sources, different syntax, different idioms, and different possible senses, which nevertheless often overlap, in the right contexts. And they're all irregular as hell.

Another issue is the [metaphoric source](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/April05Eye.pdf) of *ought*, which is, as many of us know, the old past participle of the verb *to owe*, and is caught up with the concepts of **credit** and **debit**, authority and duty. 
One *ought* to do something if one *owes* one's action (to some person, or some abstract principle) to pay a *debt*, to pay one's *due*(s), to do one's *due*-ty, etc, etc.

*Ought* (or more commonly *oughta*) is principally a weak Necessity deontic modal, like *should*,  rooted in a Face and Credit social system (rather than a Strict Authority system, like the strong Necessity modals *must* and *hafta*) but there is an epistemic sense as well, usually functioning wherever emotions can be invoked or inferred, as in anger over a misplaced item. Compare

- *Dammit! It oughta be here.*

with

- *Dammit! It should be here.*

which sounds a little weaker to my ear by comparison. But that could be personal usage bias. There's a lot of that, with all modals.

Still another issue is the use of *ought* as a **true modal auxiliary verb** (which means no *to* on  infinitive complements), or as a **semi-modal** auxiliary, (like *need* or *dare*, which allow *to* before infinitive complements, under certain circumstances).

*Ought* is a paraphrase of a true modal auxiliary (in this case *should*) that hasn't quite assimilated yet, at least not enough to lose the *to* everywhere. Like the true modal auxiliary *should*, it precedes *not*, but there are variant past constructions -- *hadn't oughta, shouldn't oughta*. Also like *should* (and *would, could, might* and *must*), it's formed from a preterite stem but can refer to the future naturally.

But *should* **never** takes *to*. However, *ought*, if it's separated from its infinitive by a negative, can suffer stack overflow, lose its modal binding field, revert to regular verb status, and allow automatic generation of an infinitive complementizer *to*. This alternation of *ought not go* vs *ought not to go* resembles the behavior of *need* and *dare*, which are also [Negative Polarity Items](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) as modals, though with a different syntax.

Outside negative polarity environments, though, the *to* in *ought to* seems likely to remain for a while. It is reinforced by the bisyllabic nature of all the periphrastic modal proto-auxiliaries *[oughta, hafta, gonna, wanna](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gonna.html),*  etc, which are all in the same kind of boat, but whose individual grammars all leak in different places.

Comment: For a moment, I thought `can suffer stack overflow` was kind of a joke. Thanks for your analysis!

Comment: Stack overflow is one of the biggest dangers in conversation. We all know people with busted stacks or weird hashing algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

In general usage, **should not**.  "Doesn't Have to" does not really make sense to me in that context, whilst "must not" appears too strong.

> A few strong branches over water reach for what they should not reach

However looking at that sentence it does seem a little odd.  I am still confident that that is the best fit.

Answer (score 2):

We normally say *A few strong branches over water reach for what they ought not **to** reach.*

I'd rephrase it as "... *reach for what they **aren't supposed to** reach*". The closest meaning to this is **should not**.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence or line in reality comes from a song entitled, **My Friends** by [*Laura Marling*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laura_marling). Click on [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPtk4tPrHSI) to watch a rendition of her song.

Furthermore, the meaning and the particular construction of the sentence is clearer when seen in its original context.

<sub>The last verse of the lyrics copied from the [website](http://www.alwaysontherun.net/lauramarling.htm); Always on the Run.</sub>

> A few good men will go where they ought
>  Where they ought not
>   be
>  And a few good mothers go for what they
>  What they ought not
>   teach
>  And I long for a touch a reminder of us but
>  But it must
>   not be
>  **And a few strong branches over water reach for**
>  **What
>   they ought not reach**

My interpretation of the line (similar to @Irene's) is that the branches touch or reach for what they ought not **to** touch or reach. In other words, the protagonist *should not* reminisce over a relationship which has *reached* its conclusion.

**Edit:** In view of @tchrist comment below, the form: ought not + verb (bare infinitive) is commonly used in the US and is considered grammatically correct.

However, consulting my trusted *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan, the accepted way to make negative infinitives in British English is by putting *not* before the infinitive. For further reference see this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36112/infinitives-with-ought-not) "Infinitives with ought not" posted in July 2011.

Comment: It turns out that *ought not ***to** do something* is ungrammatical in my own language, even though *ought to do something* is just fine. But with negation or inversion, the *to* particle disappears for me. I believe British English doesn’t mind the *to* there, but it isn’t something that I could/would/ought to say. :)

Comment: @tchrist I didn't know that "ought not + verb" is the accepted form in the US, it appears that some grammarians would also agree with you. There's a [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36112/infinitives-with-ought-not) that handles this issue, the Ngram graph results, showing "ought not to go" being more popular were a surprise for me too!